# Why VS Studio 2019 build fails not finding Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host but dotnet build is successful?

Tags: c#, azure

I have an Azure Functions project where a single Durable Function is created. When I want to build this project in VS 2019 I get the error below.
But `dotnet build` is successful, and I also can build the project from Rider.

There is no package like `Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host`, or at least I haven't found it in Nuget Package Manager.

What is wrong here? I can't decide whether VS is right, or Rider/command line is right.

> Error: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host, Version=3.0.5.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its
>   dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified. File name:
>   'Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host, Version=3.0.5.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'    at
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.GetExportedTypes(RuntimeAssembly
>   assembly, ObjectHandleOnStack retTypes)    at
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.GetExportedTypes()    at
>   MakeFunctionJson.FunctionJsonConverter.TryGenerateFunctionJsons()
>   at MakeFunctionJson.FunctionJsonConverter.TryRun()
>
> WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF. To enable assembly bind
>   failure logging, set the registry value
>   [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1. Note: There
>   is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure
>   logging. To turn this feature off, remove the registry value
>   [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].
>
> Error generating functions metadata  (1, 1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For some reasons the `AzureFunctionsVersion` in the `.csproj` file wasn't setup correctly.
I have the below and the project compiles without any error in VS 2019 too.

```
<AzureFunctionsVersion>v2</AzureFunctionsVersion>
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you try following steps

(i) Clear the NuGet cache

(ii) [`Fixing Azure Function Core Tools download issues for Visual Studio`](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-tooling-feed/wiki/Fixing-Azure-Function-Core-Tools-download-issues-for-Visual-Studio#execute-an-automated-script)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Cleaning nuget cache didn't help. I haven't found any Azure Functions and Web Jobs Tool for VS 2019.